# Flutter - SafeArea not working on phones with notches

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app that runs on mobiles. I use an Android Emulator (Pixel3 XL) with a notch in order to test SafeArea Widget but it seems to have no effect.

This is how I used the SafeArea widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: true,
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: ...,
      drawer: ...,
      body: Row(...)
  );
```

And this is the result: [image]

So, how you can see the notch is covering my appbar even if I'm using SafeArea. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `top: true,` before your `build`?

Comment: A typo. I edited the post, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
            minimum:  EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
            ..
          );
```

You can try this to solve the issue; it's working for me.